# Group together bars and labels in python matplotlib barchart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm currently trying to create a grouped and stacked bar chart using matplotlib in Python 3.x. I have only been able to get the stacked part to work and have not been able to get them to group.

```
#This is what my dataframe looks like 

     Product_set  Opened  s1     s2   s3     s4
0    Product 1  Mar-19   1    NaN    1    NaN
1    Product 1  May-19   5   89.0  210   19.0
2    Product 1  Jun-19  14  117.0  282   33.0
3    Product 1  Jul-19  12  114.0  219   27.0
4    Product 2  Apr-19   1    7.0    5    NaN
5    Product 2  May-19  10   94.0  102    6.0
6    Product 2  Jun-19  10  103.0  131   13.0
7    Product 2  Jul-19   8   82.0   98    7.0
8    Product 3  Apr-19   1   11.0   24    4.0
9    Product 3  May-19  35  157.0  318   32.0
10   Product 3  Jun-19  36  236.0  354   49.0
11   Product 3  Jul-19  31  189.0  264   30.0
12   Product 4  May-19  42  146.0  353   84.0
13   Product 4  Jun-19  61  218.0  478  103.0
14   Product 4  Jul-19  38  126.0  306  104.0
```

```py
ax=data.plot.bar(stacked=True,figsize=(20,7),edgecolor="black")

ax.minorticks_on()
plt.xticks(rotation=360)
plt.xlabel('')
plt.ylabel('')
plt.title('')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=30, size=0)

# Set minor X labels
pos = []
for bar in ax.patches:
    pos.append(bar.get_x()+bar.get_width()/2.)
ax.set_xticks(pos,minor=True)

ax.set_xticklabels(data['Product_set'])
ax.set_xticklabels(data['Opened'],minor=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I would like to make it so it only shows the product name once and there is no white space between the bars that are the same product.

Answer (score 0):

You could fake the data labels with something like

```
ax.set_xticklabels(['','','Product 1','','','','Product 2','','','','Product 3','','','Product4',''])
```

To close the spaces use `align='edge'` in your plot.bar statement, and add some spoof entries with values of 0 between products. As the date and product are only in the labels, just add another empty string for the spoofed entries

Edited: to be more dynamic

dataframe.plot.bar has an x=[positions] argument you can use. You'll need to make an array with positions, probably something like `data.index+int(data.Product_set[-1])` which would add your product # to the index, conveniently leaving an extra space between products.

Comment: I was hoping for something a little more dynamic. This is data I'm collecting on a monthly basis and the number of products and date range can vary.

Comment: align='edge' doesn't seem to be moving the bars, it's moving the labels.

Comment: If you are using the x=[positions] argument, you could also use the width=[widths] argument and just set the bars wide enough to touch which may change depending on the figure size.